# Is there any mathematical operation from which the operands can be traced back from the result without knowing one of them?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

hope everyone will be doing good.
I don't have any Mathematical background, so this question may seem awkward.
Can I perform some operation on two or more integers, by the result of which can be determined the operands, without knowing any of them.
For example, if I perform some mathemical operation on `5`, `6`, and `7`, and I get `33`(for example) as a result, how can I determine what were the original numbers before this operation was performed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Given the integers $(a,b)$ we could form the rational number $2^a3^b$, thus defining a function $F:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$.  We can, of course recover $a,b$ from $F(a,b)$.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @lulu Yes, looks like what I mean. But can you link me to some resources about this thing? I do not get what are the F, Z and Q things are. Thanks.

Comment: That's just notation.  $\mathbb Z$ just refers to the integers (from the German Zahlen).  I see that I ought to have written $\mathbb Z^2$ as $F$ takes pairs of integers, not single integers. $ \mathbb Q$ just refers to the rations (from quotient, I assume).  $F$ is jsut the name for the function $F(a,b)=2^a3^b$.  The arrow just means that $F$ is a function which, in this case, takes pairs of integers to rational numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much @lulu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by operation, you mean "any rule taking two numbers and producing a third", then yes.

---

Essentially, what you are asking is if there exists an injective (i.e., one to one) function from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, and indeed, such a function exists. For example, one such function would be $$(a,b)\mapsto 2^a\cdot 3^b$$

For example, if I take the number $48$, I can calculate what the numbers $a$ and $b$ were that matched this number. Because $48=3\cdot16=2^4\cdot3^1$, I know that $a$ was $4$ and $b$ was $1$.

However, I cannot get $33$ as a result of this operation, but there are plenty of operations where *all* integers can be their result. For example, if the operation is $$(a, b)\mapsto 2^{a-1}\cdot (2b - 1),$$ then I know that the result $33$ can only be the result of $a=1, b=17$.

Comment: In computer science such functions would be represented as reversible computations. The amount of work required to do the computation in reverse will differ greatly depending on the specific function. The _computational complexity_ of reversing the function is often important when the function is used for encryption for example.